# Iterating over Numpy matrix rows to apply a function each?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I want to be able to iterate over the matrix to apply a function to each row. How can I do it for a Numpy matrix ?

Comment: It is likely that you will get more helpful answers if you explain what you are trying to achieve / what kind of function to apply. Also, you may want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079061/function-application-over-numpys-matrix-row-column

Comment: please post your code. If you haven't tried to do it yet, go try some stuff and post what problems you have

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `numpy.apply_along_axis()`. Assuming that your array is 2D, you can use it like:

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array([[11, 12, 13],
                    [21, 22, 23],
                    [31, 32, 33]])
def myfunction(x):
    return x[0] + x[1]**2 + x[2]**3

print(np.apply_along_axis(myfunction, axis=1, arr=myarray))
#[ 2352 12672 36992]
```

Comment: if you are using `numpy` functions you can (usually) just specify the axis, like: `mymatrix.sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: that's right, the sum() in myfunction was just an example, but for some cases, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094619/fitting-a-3d-array-of-data-to-a-1d-function-with-numpy-or-scipy/16315330#16315330), `np.apply_along_axis()` can be very useful

Comment: It can be, yes - not knowing the function makes the question ambiguous.

Comment: The problem is that `apply_along_axis` is a Python for loop in disguise. It can give the illusion of numpy performance, but it will not deliver it. In the question you link, using `apply_along_axis` has no benefit over using a for loop. Trying to vectorize whatever function you want to apply to every row is the numpythonic way of doing things.

Answer (score 75):

While you should certainly provide more information, if you are trying to go through each row, you can just iterate with a for loop:

```
import numpy
m = numpy.ones((3,5),dtype='int')
for row in m:
  print str(row)
```

Comment: Isn't this an inefficient implementation?

Comment: @Lokesh, why is that?

Comment: @Brendan It's pretty late, but looping on numpy array is usually expensive because python interpreter and numpy code have to exchange the data every time the loop is executed.

Comment: @sohnryang, thanks for the response. In the past I've iterated over numpy arrays via indices (e.g. `for i in range(m)`), and that hasn't been a performance bottleneck in my experience up to 100k iterations or so. This thread seems to indicate that the assignment of each row to the `row` variable may be the slow part, so index-based iteration may be the way to go here rather than variable assignment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371021/efficient-loop-over-numpy-array

Comment: I think it will produce a wrong answer in case there is a vector as an input.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my take if you want to try using multiprocesses to process each row of numpy array,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def my_function(x):
    pass     # do something and return something

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    X = np.arange(6).reshape((3,2))
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)
    results = pool.map(my_function, map(lambda x: x, X))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

pool.map take in a function and an iterable.
I used 'map' function to create an iterator over each rows of the array.
Maybe there's a better to create the iterable though.