# Apply function to 2D numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468717/iterating-over-numpy-matrix-rows-to-apply-a-function-each) and want to do something similar, but not exactly the same.

I am implementing a little *game of life* game and using `numpy arrays` for representing the *states* of the game. So I need to check, how many *alive neighbors* a *cell* has. I already got a function for getting a *window of neighbors* given a coordinate and row count and column count for the window size that I want to have.

So usually my windows will be of 3x3 size like this:

```
T = True
F = False
[[T,T,T],
 [F,T,T],
 [F,F,F]]  # some random truth values
```

In this representation `True` stands for a cell being alive.
Now I wrote some code iterating over all cells of the state, counting the True values and so on using a double for loop, but I think there is probably a better numpy solution.

What I'd do in the naive approach:

1. iterate over all cells of the state (not only the window) (I'd like to formulate some code to to be executed if a cell meets a criteria or another (being alive and surviving or being dead and coming alive))
2. get the window (wrapping or not wrapping) (function for that I already have)
3. check if the current cell is alive (could just do a lookup in the state's numpy array)
4. if it is alive start with an alive neighbors count of -1 otherwise start with 0
5. count all True values of the window (`np.sum`) and add it to the alive neighbors count (which is -1 if the cell itself was alive, so that I only count neighbors but not the cell itself)
6. depending on whether the count of alive neighbors is in certain ranges (configurable), write in another (new) state's array `True` values. (I'd start out with an array, which I created using: `np.full((height, width), False, dtype=bool)`)
7. go on with that new array, keeping the old one in a list for history or logging purposes

Basically:

```
if cell meets criteria:
    write True at the cell's position in a new array
```

However meeting the criteria depends on multiple rows, because the state's numpy array is a 2D array. That's why I think the linked post is close but not exactly what I need.

How can I do this in an efficient numpy-y way, avoiding unnecessary looping?

**Clarification**

I am searching for the best way of implementing this in python using numpy and scipy, which aims to be very readable and has good performance.

Comment: Write a version that does all the iterations explicitly, but clearly.  And give us a test case to use with it.  Then we can help streamline it, most likely starting with the inner most loop, where you do the `sum`.

Comment: You could probably do this easily with `scipy.ndimage.filters` with a window size of 3.  Treating True as 1 and False as 0, a `generic_filter` might work, with `function=lambda a: 1 if a.sum() - a[4] > 4 else 0`.  But it's tough to say without explicit input/output examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I did not understand all you are trying to do, but what is stopping you from simply using the `numpy.sum` function?

Example - Let the state be:

```
import numpy as np
state = np.random.randint(1, 10, (9,9))
```

Here I am using {0, 1} as values for the state, where 1 means "alive".
Then you can just slice around the cell being investigated, e.g. [2,3]

```
s = state[1:3,2:5]
if s[1,1]:
   val = -1
else
   val = 0
val += s.sum()
```

If you put this in a for loop and pay attention to border cases, clamping or wrapping as appropriate, it should do what you describe.

If you are looking for a short elegant implementation, it can be done very [efficiently with Python and Numpy](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/07/conways-game-of-life/).

Comment: Sounds good so far. I only would like to avoid that loop looping over all cells and each iteration slicing etc. - If this is somehow possible.
That link :D I should've searched for something like a solution before I started ... I'll check it and see if I can adopt the code.

Comment: The loop is implicit in the problem: you have to sum the value of the neighbors in the end. Even the very elegant code in the link is using a generator expression with a nested loop, which has to be executed one way or the other.

Comment: Cybr..., you are treating `s` like a nested list, not an array.

Comment: @hpaulj True! Got my syntax mixed up (been programming too much in C :), thank you and fixed.

Comment: I was thinking you'd also want to do some boolean masking, but you are only testing one item in `s`.  So that `if` is ok ( `val = -1 if s[1,1] else 0` is minor alternative).

Comment: So much could be done to make it better.. if you write a full example, I will vote you up!

Comment: It states: _"Note that neither of these are extremely performant: they involve creating several temporary arrays, and will not work well for large problems with many time steps."_ Is there a faster way using numpy and scipy than the convolve2d function?

Comment: @Zelphir Not that I am aware of. If you are really looking for performance for *game of life* you need to go to a compiled language and probably implement HashLife.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r I think I don't need super performance, but I'd like to do it in a way, that no one could say _"You could have done that in an easier, more readable way, which is more performant!"_ I still don't understand why convolve2d does exactly what I want. I know convolve operation from image processing, but it was used to determin things given precisely the position of other pixels, not only the count of those, so I am not sure why it still works.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r I finally understood what that code on the website is doing completely. Thanks for sharing that link, I feel confident in that solution now.