# Extract non- empty values from the regex array output in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of type numpy.ndarray which looks like:

```
         col
    ['','','5','']
    ['','8']
    ['6','','']
    ['7']
    []
    ['5']
```

I want the ouput like this :

```
         col
          5
          8
          6
          7
          0
          5
```

How can I do this in python.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What about `['']` and `['5', '6']`?

Comment: In my case I only have single non empty entry. But in such cases is it possible to get the maximum from the list. In this case    ['5', '6'] should give me 6. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the data to numeric values you could use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = list(map(np.array, [ ['','','5',''], ['','8'], ['6','',''], ['7'], [], ['5']]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': data})
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.join('')).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   col
0    5
1    8
2    6
3    7
4    0
5    5
```

---

To convert the data to strings use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.join('').replace('', '0')
```

The result looks the same, but the dtype of the column is `object` since the values are strings.

---

If there is more than one number in some rows and you wish to pick the largest,
then you'll have to loop through each item in each row, convert each string to
a numeric value and take the max:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = list(map(np.array, [ ['','','5','6'], ['','8'], ['6','',''], ['7'], [], ['5']]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': data})
df['col'] = [max([int(xi) if xi else 0 for xi in x] or [0]) for x in df['col']]
print(df)
```

yields

```
   col
0    6   # <-- note  ['','','5','6'] was converted to 6
1    8
2    6
3    7
4    0
5    5
```

---

For versions of pandas prior to 0.17, you could use `df.convert_objects` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = list(map(np.array, [ ['','','5',''], ['','8'], ['6','',''], ['7'], [], ['5']]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': data})
df['col'] = df['col'].str.join('').replace('', '0')
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Comment: Why do you need the `data = list(map(np.array, ...`? Can it be just `data = np.array(...)`

Comment: I am getting "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_numeric' ". How  to get around it. Thanks

Comment: @JoeR: If you define `data` as a NumPy object array, then `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` will make the values lists, not NumPy arrays. Since the OP said "column of type numpy.ndarray" I tried to adhere to this specification (just in case it makes a difference, though I don't think it does.)

Comment: @user4349490: `pd.to_numeric` is a somewhat recent addition to pandas. In earlier versions there was a a [`df.convert_objects` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html). If you can update your version of pandas, I'd recommend doing so. Otherwise, try `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Thank you for the great answer btw. and the great jokes on your profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave you with this :

```
>>> l=['', '5', '', '']
>>> l = [x for x in l if not len(x) == 0]
>>> l
>>> ['5']
```

You can do the same thing using lambda and filter

```
>>> l
['', '1', '']
>>> l = filter(lambda x: not len(x)==0, l)
>>> l
['1']
```

The next step would be iterating through the rows of the array and implementing one of these two ideas.

Someone shows how this is done here: [Iterating over Numpy matrix rows to apply a function each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468717/iterating-over-numpy-matrix-rows-to-apply-a-function-each)

edit: maybe this is down-voted, but I made it on purpose to not give the final code.

Comment: The OP wanted integers in the output and you have strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
     xn = array([['', '', '5', ''], ['', '8'], ['6', '', ''], ['7'], [], ['5']],
    dtype=object)

        In [20]: for a in x:
   ....:     if len(a)==0:
   ....:         print 0
   ....:     else:
   ....:         for b in a:
   ....:             if b:
   ....:                 print b
   ....:
5
8
6
7
0
5
```