# how to apply a generic function over numpy rows?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Before you flag this as duplicate, let me explain to you that I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468717/iterating-over-numpy-matrix-rows-to-apply-a-function-each) and many others and I still haven't found a solution to my problem.

This is the problem I'm having: given two 2D arrays, I want to apply a function F over the two arrays. F takes as input two 1D arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15).reshape([3,5])
b = np.arange(30, step=2).reshape([3,5])

# what is the 'numpy' equivalent of the following?
np.array([np.dot(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Please note that `np.dot` is just for demonstration. The real question here is any generic function F that works over two sets of 1D arrays.

- vectorizing either fails outright with an error or it applies the function element-by-element, instead of array-by-array (or row-by-row)
- `np.apply_along_axis` applies the function iteratively; for example, using the variables defined above, it does `F(a[0], b[0])` and combines this with `F(a[0], b[1])` and `F(a[0], b[2])`. This is not what I'm looking for. Ideally, I would want it to stop at just `F(a[0], b[0])`
- index slicing / advanced slicing doesn't do what I would like either. For one, if I do something like `np.dot(a[np.arange(3)], b[np.arange(3)])` this throws a ValueError saying that shapes (3,5) and (3,5) are not aligned. I don't know how to fix this.

I tried to solve this in any way I could, but the only solution I've come up with that works is using list comprehension. But I'm worried about the cost to performance as a result of using list comprehension. I would like to achieve the same effect using a numpy operation, if possible. How do I do this?

Comment: If you need to vectorize, we need to see the actual implementation, No shortcuts there. `np.apply_along_axis` is still mostly a loop, it doesn't give you noticeable improvement in most cases.

Comment: You have already the inner loop executed by Numpy, are you sure of your need to vectorize (the outer loop)?

Comment: the code I wrote is basically the implementation itself. Ok maybe it's not the *actual* implementation, but it's easier to deal with. The actual one just has bigger arrays that are initialized differently.

Comment: @gboffi, wouldn't it be better? I used small arrays in my post but this needs to be scaled to much larger arrays, so I'm trying to avoid Python list comprehensions if possible

Comment: If it  is an inner, outer or mixed product, it can be easily solved using `np.einsum()` but you stated that it's not a dot product so to be able to provide a solution it is _necessary_ to know something about `F`, to know that's a generic function that accepts two 1D arrays of the same shape is vague, or at least it seems to me. Possibly my fault...

Comment: Re inner vs outer loops — if your arrays are `(1000000,3)` optimizing the outer loop may be sensible but if your arrays are `(3,1000000)` , well I dare say that you are saving large chunks of almost nothing... — Of course your case can be intermediate, meaning that you need a vectorized solution to understand what's better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of question has been beat to death on SO, but I'll try to illustrate the issues with your framework:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(15).reshape([3,5])
   ...: b = np.arange(30, step=2).reshape([3,5])
   ...: 
In [2]: def f(x,y):
   ...:     return np.dot(x,y)
```

### zipped comprehension

The list comprehension approach applies `f` to the 3 rows of `a` and `b`.  That is, it iterates on the 2 arrays as through they were lists.  At each call, your function gets 2 1d arrays.  `dot` can accept other shapes, but for the moment we'll pretend that it only works with a pair of 1ds

```
In [3]: np.array([f(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
Out[3]: array([  60,  510, 1460])
In [4]: np.dot(a[0],b[0])
Out[4]: 60
```

### vectorize/frompyfunc

`np.vectorize` iterates over the inputs (with broadcasting - which can be handy), and gives the function scalar values.  I'll illustrate with `frompyfunc` returns a object dtype array (and is used by `vectorize`):

```
In [5]: vf = np.frompyfunc(f, 2,1)
In [6]: vf(a,b)
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 2, 8, 18, 32],
       [50, 72, 98, 128, 162],
       [200, 242, 288, 338, 392]], dtype=object)
```

So the result is (3,5) array; incidentally summing across columns gets the desired result

```
In [9]: vf(a,b).sum(axis=1)
Out[9]: array([60, 510, 1460], dtype=object)
```

`np.vectorize` does not make any speed promises.

### apply_along_axis

I don't know how you tried to use `apply_along_axis`.  It only takes one array.  After a lot of set up it ends up doing (for a 2d array like `a`):

```
for i in range(3):
    idx = (i, slice(None))
    outarr[idx] = asanyarray(func1d(arr[idx], *args, **kwargs))
```

For 3d and larger it makes iteration over the 'other' axes simpler; for 2d it is overkill.  In any case it does not speed up the calculations.  It is still iteration.

(`apply_along_axis` takes `arr` and `*args`. It iterates on `arr`, but uses `*args` whole.).

### indexing

```
np.dot(a[np.arange(3)], b[np.arange(3)])
```

is the same as

```
np.dot(a, b)
```

`dot` is matrix product, (3,5) works with (5,3) to produce a (3,3).  It handles 1d as a special case (see docs), (3,) with (3,) produces (3,).

### iteration

For a truly generic `f(x,y)`, your only alternative to the zipped list comprehension is an index loop like this:

```
In [18]: c = np.zeros((a.shape[0]))
In [19]: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    ...:    c[i] = f(a[i,:], b[i,:])
In [20]: c
Out[20]: array([   60.,   510.,  1460.])
```

Speed will be similar.   (that action can be moved to compiled code with `cython`, but I don't think you are ready to dive in that deep.)

As noted in a comment, if the arrays are `(N,M)`, and `N` is small compared to `M`, this iteration is not costly.  That is, a few loops over a big task are ok.  They may even be faster if they simplify large array memory management.

### best

The ideal solution is to rewrite the generic function so it works with 2d arrays, using numpy compilied functions.

In the matrix multiplication case, `einsum` has implemented a generalized form of 'sum-of-products' in compiled code:

```
In [22]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
Out[22]: array([  60,  510, 1460])
```

`matmul` also generalizes the product, but works best with 3d arrays:

```
In [25]: a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None]    # needs reshape
Out[25]: 
array([[[  60]],

       [[ 510]],

       [[1460]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from **generic functions** if you want a fast solution with NumPy. Even though NumPy has some capabilities to **hide** python loops the loops are still present (inside the function) and these solutions aren't really fast (at least compared to normal NumPy functions).

What you should do is: Find a function in NumPy, SciPy, ... that does what you need. These functions are fast, but it sometimes takes a bit of searching and/or experimentation until you find a match.

For example a vector-dot product is just the sum along rows of the element-wise multiplication:

```
np.sum(a * b, axis=1)        # array([  60,  510, 1460])

np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)  # array([  60,  510, 1460])
```