# Apply custom function to 2 or more rows (or columns) in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am fairly new to `numpy.` I want to apply a custom function to 1, 2 or more rows (or columns). How can I do this? Before this is marked as duplicate, I want to point out that the only thread I found that does this is [how to apply a generic function over numpy rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239498/how-to-apply-a-generic-function-over-numpy-rows) and [how to apply a generic function over numpy rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239498/how-to-apply-a-generic-function-over-numpy-rows). There are two issues with this post:

a) As a beginner, I am not quite sure what operation like `A[:,None,:]` does.

b) That operation doesn't work in my case. Please see below.

Let's assume that Matrix M is:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[8, 3, 2],
              [6, 1, 2],
              [1, 2, 4]])
```

Now, I would want to calculate product of combination of all three rows. For this, I have created a **custom** function. Actual operation of the function could be different from multiplication. Multiplication is **just an example.**

```
def myf(a,b): return(a*b)
```

I have taken `numpy` array product as an example. Actual custom function could be different, but no matter what the operation is, the function will always return a `numpy` array. i.e. it will take two equally-sized `numpy` 1-D array and return 1-D array. In `myf` I am assuming that `a` and `b` are each `np.array`.

I want to be able to apply custom function to any two rows or columns, or even three rows (recursively applying function).

Expected output after multiplying two rows recursively:

If I apply pairwise row-operation:

```
[[48,3,4],
 [6,2,8],
 [8,6,8]]
```

OR ( The order of application of custom function doesn't matter. Hence, the actual position of rows in the output matrix won't matter. Below matrix will be fine as well.)

```
[[6,2,8],
 [48,3,4],  #row1 and 2 are swapped
 [8,6,8]]
```

Similarly, if I apply pairwise operation on columns, I would get

```
[[24, 6, 16]
 [6,  2, 12] 
 [2,  8, 4]]
```

Similarly, if I apply custom function to all three rows, I would get:

```
[48,6,16] #row-wise
```

OR

```
[48,12,8] #column-wise
```

I tried a few approaches after reading SO:

## 1:

```
vf=np.vectorize(myf)
vf(M,M)
```

However, above function applies custom function element-wise rather than row-wise or columnwise.

## 2:

I also tried:

```
M[:,None,:].dot(M) #dot mimics multiplication. Python wouldn't accept `*`
```

There are two problems with this:

a) I don't know what the output is.

b) I cannot apply custom function.

Can someone please help me? I'd appreciate any help.

I am open to `numpy` and `scipy`.

---

Some experts have requested desired output. Let's assume that the desired output is 
`[[48,3,4],
 [6,2,8],
 [8,6,8]]`.

However, I'd appreciate some guidance on customizing the solution for 2 or more columns and 2 or more rows.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: In your example, you are "rolling" your function over (wrapped) `numpy` array rather than what the title seems to indicate: apply some multivariate function over more than one (but specific) rows. This actually makes things much more complicated

Comment: @Nils Werner. Thanks. Can we apply custom function to rows? `[[48,3,4],
 [6,2,8],
 [8,6,8]]` Also, I'd appreciate if the solution to be customizable for 2 or more columns and 2 or more rows.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)?

Comment: @ZizisNot...Do you want me to change the title? If so, I'd appreciate if you could suggest something. I am not sure about it.

Comment: @Nils Werner: I think I gave sample output with row multiplication. Is anything missing? I have also provided sample input.

Comment: I would say something like "*roll custom multivariate function over `numpy` array with wrapped boundary*". The "row" here isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply roll your axis along the `0`th axis

```
np.roll(M, -1, axis=0)
# array([[6, 1, 2],
#        [1, 2, 4],
#        [8, 3, 2]])
```

And multiply the result with your original array

```
M * np.roll(M, -1, axis=0)
# array([[48,  3,  4],
#        [ 6,  2,  8],
#        [ 8,  6,  8]])
```

If you want to incorporate more than two rows, you can roll it more than once:

```
M * np.roll(M, -1, axis=0) * np.roll(M, -2, axis=0)
# array([[48,  6, 16],
#        [48,  6, 16],
#        [48,  6, 16]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to use the custom function?

Comment: That heavily depends on what your custom function does.

Comment: Thanks. It would *always* accept two 1-D `numpy` array of same dimension and return 1-D `numpy` array. I believe I have clarified this in the question.

Comment: Then no. It needs to accept 2D arrays. But in many cases, a function that accepts 1D arrays can be made to accept 2D arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining why it must accept 2D arrays. I am curious. I didn't follow the logic.

Comment: Because both arrays are 2D. You can iterate over it rowwise, but that will make things slow. Just open a new question with your actual function and ask how you can vectorize it to 2D operations.