# Iterate over a numpy Matrix rows

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

First, I tried to find an answer to my question ( which I think is pretty basic) searching in google and in the site, but nothing came up.

I'm trying to get the rows from a numpy matrix, but I can't. For example if I use this:

```
result = numpy.matrix([[11, 12, 13],
                       [21, 22, 23],
                       [31, 32, 33]])

for p in result:
    print(p[0])
```

prints this:

```
[[11 12 13]]
[[21 22 23]]
[[31 32 33]]
```

The same if I use just `p`

What I have to do to access every row? `numpy.nditer(result)` prints an array, and I need every row to perform some operations.

Comment: It looks like you are accessing rows.  Do you mean columns?

Comment: You are fetching the rows.  It's just that rows of a `np.matrix` are still `np.matrix`, and display as 2d.

Comment: As jpp sayed, you may want to use arrays. But if you insist on using matrices (for the convinience of multiplication, for example) then refer to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468717/iterating-over-numpy-matrix-rows-to-apply-a-function-each

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is you are using `np.matrix`. Use `np.array` instead and simply iterate without indexing:

```
result = np.array([[11, 12, 13],
                   [21, 22, 23],
                   [31, 32, 33]])

for p in result:
    print(p)

[11 12 13]
[21 22 23]
[31 32 33]
```

**Explanation**

What you are seeing is the effect of `numpy.matrix` requiring each *row* to have 2 dimensions. This is unnecessary and anti-pattern for NumPy.

There is a history behind `numpy.matrix`. It was used initial for convenience of matrix multiplication operators. But this is no longer an issue since `@` is possible (Python 3.5+) instead of nested `dot` calls. Therefore, by default, use `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
for p in result:
    print(numpy.array(p)[0])
```

This gives you each row as a `numpy.ndarray`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways (both essentially boils down to same logic)

#### method-1:

Use [`result.A`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html)

Return `self` as an `ndarray` object.
Equivalent to `np.asarray(self)`.

```
In [16]: for row in result.A:
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     
[11 12 13]
[21 22 23]
[31 32 33]
```

---

#### method-2:

Use [`result.getA()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getA.html)

Return `self` as an `ndarray` object.
Equivalent to `np.asarray(self)`.

```
In [17]: for row in result.getA():
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     
[11 12 13]
[21 22 23]
[31 32 33]
```